# Calculating cube root: OverflowError: ('Result too large')

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm supposed to create a code that calculates the cube root of an inputted number with the approximation of up to 2 decimal places. This code above calculates the square root of a number with up to 2 decimal places:

```
epsilon = 0.01
guess = num/2.0
while abs(guess**2 - num) >= epsilon:
    guess = guess - abs(guess**2 - num) / (2 * guess)
print("Guess:", guess)
```

So apparently I am able to do the cube root with that criteria by modifying this code that was given and using this in the code:

```
delta = abs(guess**3 - num) / 100.0
```

I tried using that line and modifying the code used for square root and I keep getting:

```
OverflowError: ('Result too large')
```

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
epsilon = 0.01
guess = num/2.0
while abs(guess**3 - num) >= epsilon:
    guess = abs(guess - (guess**3 - num)/100.0)
print("Guess:", guess)
```

When I run that code above this is what happens:

> runfile('C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U/edits.py', runfile('C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U/edits.py', wdir='C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U')
>
> Enter a number: 34 Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in runfile('C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U/edits.py', wdir='C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/100617828/Documents/CSCI1040U/edits.py", line 11, in while abs(guess**3 - num) >= epsilon:
>
> OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

**Edit**
[image]

This is what my assignment sheet is telling me to do but it seems I don't need to use `delta = abs(guess**3 - num)/100.0` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the **full text** of the traceback, filenames, line numbers, and all. Do you understand the mathematics of how to calculate a cube root?

Comment: Do you need that iterative approximation? How does `x**(1/3)` work for you?

Comment: Sorry first time using stackoverflow I included the traceback and I do understand that in a simple equation you can calculate the cube root just by having a number to the exponent of (1/3).

Comment: Why do you believe that you can use `delta = abs(guess**3 - num) / 100.0`, when the case for the square root is nothing like that. (This is Newton's Iterative Method btw)

Comment: It was just in my assignment instructions and was given as a hint, I don't even know how the code works to be honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are using is called [Newton-Raphson approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), and you should use the first derivative of the function you are trying to solve as the denominator. Because the first derivative of `x^3` is `3*x^2`,  the iteration line must be:

```
guess = guess - abs(guess**3 - num) / (3 * guess**2)
```

See the working code at https://repl.it/DqZA/0

Comment: Sorry can I ask you to explain more? You seem to be able to get the correct approximation but my teacher and in my assignment instructions it gave this "delta = abs(guess**3 - num) / 100.0" as a hint. I'm not quite sure of how the code just works in general both the fixed one you showed me and the one I was given as an example.

Comment: @Langfao I'm not sure about that hint (maybe it was a red herring), but if you examine the first (square root) example you will see that the denominator is not a constant but `(2 * guess)`. This comes from the fact that the derivative of `x^2`  is `2*x`. You can read the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to learn more about the maths of the method.

Comment: was that hint really meant to throw people off? I'm in an intro to programming class and I'm a novice at coding and many other people in my class are as well.

Comment: @Langfao I wouldn't say that, but maybe your instructor wanted you to do a little research and find the correct formula by yourself.